# SqlDataReader Best way to check for null values -sqlDataReader.IsDBNull vs DBNull.Value

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldatareader, dbnull

I want to retrieve decimal values from the database and I would like to know which is the recommended way to check for null values.

I have seen on [MSDN - DBNull.Value Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)  that this check is rarely used.

Thus, is the `reader.IsDBNull` the best/most efficient way to check for nulls?

I have created 2 sample methods:

```
public static decimal? GetNullableDecimal(SqlDataReader reader, string fieldName)
{
    if (reader[fieldName] == DBNull.Value)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return (decimal)reader[fieldName];
}

public static decimal? GetNullableDecimal_2(SqlDataReader reader, string fieldName)
{
    if (reader.IsDBNull(reader[fieldName]))
    {
         return null;
    }
    return (decimal)reader[fieldName];
}
```

Most of the time the fields are going to be null.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which ever one you prefer and find most readable. However, it is worth noting your examples are not strictly equivalent given the use of `reader.GetOrdinal` in the second.

Comment: Internally the syntax `reader[fieldName]` is resolved to `reader.GetOrdinal(fieldName)`

Comment: I 've amended the example to use reader[fieldName] in both cases

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would not get too caught up in the which method is better, because both work and I have used both in code before.

For instance, here is a utility function I dug up from one of my old projects:

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper class for SqlDataReader, which allows for the calling code to retrieve a value in a generic fashion.
/// </summary>
public static class SqlReaderHelper
{
    private static bool IsNullableType(Type theValueType)
    {
        return (theValueType.IsGenericType && theValueType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the value, of type T, from the SqlDataReader, accounting for both generic and non-generic types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">T, type applied</typeparam>
    /// <param name="theReader">The SqlDataReader object that queried the database</param>
    /// <param name="theColumnName">The column of data to retrieve a value from</param>
    /// <returns>T, type applied; default value of type if database value is null</returns>
    public static T GetValue<T>(this SqlDataReader theReader, string theColumnName)
    {
        // Read the value out of the reader by string (column name); returns object
        object theValue = theReader[theColumnName];

        // Cast to the generic type applied to this method (i.e. int?)
        Type theValueType = typeof(T);

        // Check for null value from the database
        if (DBNull.Value != theValue)
        {
            // We have a null, do we have a nullable type for T?
            if (!IsNullableType(theValueType))
            {
                // No, this is not a nullable type so just change the value's type from object to T
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(theValue, theValueType);
            }
            else
            {
                // Yes, this is a nullable type so change the value's type from object to the underlying type of T
                NullableConverter theNullableConverter = new NullableConverter(theValueType);

                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(theValue, theNullableConverter.UnderlyingType);
            }
        }

        // The value was null in the database, so return the default value for T; this will vary based on what T is (i.e. int has a default of 0)
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
yourSqlReaderObject.GetValue<int?>("SOME_ID_COLUMN");
yourSqlReaderObject.GetValue<string>("SOME_VALUE_COLUMN");
```

Comment: Awesome!   I have only one recommendation for adjustment to this.. change this GetValue<T>SqlDataReader to GetValue<T>(this IDataRecord

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check for null and handle it (as opposed to checking for null and alerting the program that it was null) you can use the `as` operator with the null-coalescing operator `??`.
So in my program

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    response.Employees.Add(new Employee() { Id = dr["id"] as int? ?? default(int), ImageUrl = dr["Photo"] as string, JobTitle = dr["JobTitle"] as string });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simpler version of @Karl Anderson's answer:

```
public static class DbHelper
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(this SqlDataReader sqlDataReader, string columnName)
    {
        var value = sqlDataReader[columnName];

        if (value != DBNull.Value)
        {
            return (T)value;
        }

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
public static class DbHelper
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(this SqlDataReader sqlDataReader, string columnName)
    {
        var value = sqlDataReader[columnName];

        return value == DBNull.Value ? default(T) : (T) value;
    }
}
```

Direct casting seems to work just fine for either nullable or non-nullable types.