# Get Value of Tuple From MySQL into String Array

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, datareader

I want to select all rows and columns from database (There's no conditions) and store each tuple (for example: value of index[0,0] in the table) in an String array..

Here's the code i am using:

```
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("S;Port=P;Database=DB;Uid=U;Pwd=P"))                      {
       connection.Open();
       MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd=connection.CreateCommand();
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
       MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader datr = cmd.ExecuteReader();            
       coun = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
       while (datr.Read()){
            for (int i = 0; i < coun; i++)  {                          
                 First_String[i] = datr[0].ToString();
                 Second_String[i] = datr[1].ToString();
                Third_String[i] = datr[2].ToString();
                        /* and so on...*/   
             }
       }
}
```

I am getting an error which is: Object not "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

What the wrong thing am doing?

Thanks

Comment: The inner loop is meaningless. You're repeating the same data coun times. While(data.Read()) does what you're trying to do with the inner loop.

Comment: Make sure to initialize your first, second and third arrays, also check your database if any null values exists

Comment: What row is throwing the error ? since not all of your code is visible.

Comment: @user3185569 but how the data will be filled in the string arrays? they need an index which is "i" in the for loop

Comment: @CuriousPen, how to do the initialization of arrays?, and there's no null values in the database.

Comment: @user3185569, the error starts at line number 9

Comment: @Izzo32 In the second While iteration , Data will be overwritten because i will be 0 again.

Comment: @Izzo32 like First_String=new string[column_count_of db_table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("S;Port=P;Database=DB;Uid=U;Pwd=P"))                      {
       connection.Open();
       MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd=connection.CreateCommand();
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
       MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader datr = cmd.ExecuteReader();            
       coun = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
       int counter = 0;
       string[] First_String = new string[datr.FieldCount];
       string[] Second_String = new string[datr.FieldCount];
       string[] Third_String = new string[datr.FieldCount];
       while (datr.Read()){                          
                 First_String[counter] = datr[0].ToString();
                 Second_String[counter] = datr[1].ToString();
                Third_String[counter] = datr[2].ToString();
                        /* and so on...*/   
                counter++;
       }
}
```

Comment: i think you didn't initialize you arrays :/

Comment: Yes i tried your code, i got the same error but at the end of code at >> counter++

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{

    public static string SafeGetString(this SqlDataReader reader, int colIndex)
    {
       if(!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
           return reader.GetString(colIndex);
       else 
           return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Change your code to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < coun; i++)
{
 First_String[i] = datr.SafeGetString(0);
 Second_String[i] = datr.SafeGetString(1);
 Third_String[i] = datr.SafeGetString(2);
}
```

Comment: Can you set a break point and tell me what line is caused the exception?

Comment: are you sure that your table has at least 3 columns?

Comment: @Izzo32 p.s. for looping through columns you dont need to run `coun = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` just use `datr.FieldCount`

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are working with datareader a lot you can use this helper class from this post

[SqlDataReader Best way to check for null values -sqlDataReader.IsDBNull vs DBNull.Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550769/sqldatareader-best-way-to-check-for-null-values-sqldatareader-isdbnull-vs-dbnul)

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper class for SqlDataReader, which allows for the calling code to retrieve a value in a generic fashion.
/// </summary>
public static class SqlReaderHelper
{
    private static bool IsNullableType(Type theValueType)
    {
        return (theValueType.IsGenericType && theValueType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the value, of type T, from the SqlDataReader, accounting for both generic and non-generic types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">T, type applied</typeparam>
    /// <param name="theReader">The SqlDataReader object that queried the database</param>
    /// <param name="theColumnName">The column of data to retrieve a value from</param>
    /// <returns>T, type applied; default value of type if database value is null</returns>
    public static T GetValue<T>(this SqlDataReader theReader, string theColumnName)
    {
        // Read the value out of the reader by string (column name); returns object
        object theValue = theReader[theColumnName];

        // Cast to the generic type applied to this method (i.e. int?)
        Type theValueType = typeof(T);

        // Check for null value from the database
        if (DBNull.Value != theValue)
        {
            // We have a null, do we have a nullable type for T?
            if (!IsNullableType(theValueType))
            {
                // No, this is not a nullable type so just change the value's type from object to T
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(theValue, theValueType);
            }
            else
            {
                // Yes, this is a nullable type so change the value's type from object to the underlying type of T
                NullableConverter theNullableConverter = new NullableConverter(theValueType);

                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(theValue, theNullableConverter.UnderlyingType);
            }
        }

        // The value was null in the database, so return the default value for T; this will vary based on what T is (i.e. int has a default of 0)
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
yourSqlReaderObject.GetValue<int?>("SOME_ID_COLUMN");
yourSqlReaderObject.GetValue<string>("SOME_VALUE_COLUMN");
```