# How to return zero when no record is found from the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am getting the below error each time I run my project.

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'

My requirement is to return zero even when there is no row from the database.

```
public int Plantcount()
    {
        var query = "SELECT Sum(Amount ) as Total FROM Carttable";
        string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        int totalAmount = 0;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        totalAmount = dr.GetInt32(0); 
                    }
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return totalAmount;
    }
```

| Id | Item | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| - | - | - |

Expected output

| Total |
| --- |
| 0 |

Comment: You should use a proper ORM like Entity Framework Core, which handles this sort of case for you.

Comment: @IanKemp  No need for EF here in this limited scope; this can simply be handled in either the SQL or C# here without that extra layer.

Comment: This is closely related here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1772025/125981 or even https://stackoverflow.com/q/18550769/125981  or https://stackoverflow.com/q/1772025/125981 or several other similar questions - might even be considered duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNULL function in your SQL query, which will ensure a 0 is returned when the sum is NULL.

```
var query = "SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount), 0) AS Total FROM Carttable";
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the Plantcount() method returns '0' even when there are no rows in the database, you can use COALESCE to handle null values and ensure that a default of zero is returned:

```
public int Plantcount()
{
    var query = "SELECT COALESCE(Sum(Amount), 0) as Total FROM Carttable";
    string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    int totalAmount = 0;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    totalAmount = dr.GetInt32(0);
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    return totalAmount;
}
```

If no rows exist in your Carttable, SUM function will return null, and COALESCE(Sum(Amount), 0) will replace that null with zero.